# No such property in Groovy test case

Tags: unit-testing, groovy

I have a Groovy test class `MsgDispatcherTest extends GroovyTestCase`.
Within this class there is the following test case:

```
@Test
void test_register()
{
    def d = MsgDispatcher.instance    // MsgDispatcher is a singelton
    def cb1Called = 0
    def cb1 = { cb1Called++; void }

    d.registerCallback("msg1", cb1)   // closure cb1 should be registered
}
```

And the interface of `MsgDispatcher.registerCallback` looks like this:

```
void registerCallback(String message, Closure callback)
{
    assert callback && message
    // ...
}
```

Now when I run this test case I get the following error message on the call to `d.registerCallback("msg1", cb1)`:

*groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: msg1 for class: ecs.MsgDispatcherTest*

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: There are no errors in the code you've provided so far, so I guess that it occurs later. Perhaps you could provide the rest of the `registerCallback` method?

Comment: .. and `MsgDispatcher` if feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. There was a bug in my `registerCallback()` method. The issue was that I have tried to access the `callback` parameter as map (`callback[message]`), which of course does not work.

That's ok, I understand why this is a problem. However, why is the Groovy compiler error message so cryptic? It was referring not to that problematic line within `registerCallback()`, but instead to the line where I call that function.